# How does fabric aggregate crashes?

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

Does it use only the last function call or a few functions after that ? 
Because I have a few callstacks that are different but they do end up in the same function call (a crash handler) and fabric aggregates them all in the same crashes but they have a very different callstack !

Comment: Good questions Miahi. We constantly make updates to improve grouping, however this is just something that we have to live with for now. I'll let the team know you are interested in manual grouping. :)

Comment: it would be awesome if i can get an option per project to specify the "depth" or how many layers to check to see if the callstacks are "mergeable".

Comment: Hah, logged in to ask about essentially the same thing. The grouping is a bit iffy sometimes, and being able to break crashes up manually (or a depth) would be super helpful